# Android play video from URL

Tags: android

When i play video from sdcard and raw folders the video is playing fine.
But when i play video from remote server URL based it is not playing with VideoView,
what could be the reson?

I have to play video cotninously without stop/pause from URL(server hit)based.

please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are requirements on the protocol and the media file format that can be played by the MediaPlayer.

You need to refer to this chart, if you have not done so already:
https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

```
String SrcPath="http://akamedia2.lsops.net/live/smil:cnbc_en.smil/playlist.m3u8";
        myVideoView = new VideoView(this);
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
        setContentView(myVideoView);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
```

try this code.Hop its helpful to you.