# Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side Error in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have tried to play a youtube video by its URL by my android program.
I have used setVideoURI(uri);   function also to set URI, as suggested by other POSTs in stackoverflow  regarding this.
But I am getting **Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side** error.
Can you please figure out what is the problem with my code.

But I am able to play any local video by commented code.

Here is my android code-

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

    //MediaPlayer song= new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.VVSimpleVideo);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        //String _path = "mnt/sdcard/Movies/MyCameraApp/video6.mp4";
        String _path = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43mgXNl0xc";
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(_path);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
       //videoView.setVideoPath(_path);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_video, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the Log Error-

```
  10-11 04:51:23.480: D/MediaPlayer(4714): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-11 04:51:26.130: E/MediaPlayer(4714): error (1, -2147483648)
10-11 04:51:26.130: E/MediaPlayer(4714): Error (1,-2147483648)
10-11 04:51:26.130: D/VideoView(4714): Error: 1,-2147483648
10-11 04:51:26.190: D/dalvikvm(4714): GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 4% free 6785K/7047K, paused 4ms+3ms
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to play video rtsp format in video view.

Comment: You can refer these links to play video from url:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597800/android-play-video-from-url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the You tube url..., Substring the Video_ID from the Url.See the example below i have given.

once you get the rtsp link you can play video in VideoView [Here is example](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html).

For example: If this link is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43mgXNl0xc

Then `E43mgXNl0xc`  is the Video_ID.

Use this video id to play video in videoview.

Refer these two links:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716146/rtsp-youtube-link)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520313/how-to-get-rtsp-links-android)

Once you get the rtsp link you can play it in VideoView.

Also check my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937615/how-to-play-youtube-video-on-videoview/11185129#11185129).

Comment: "Q-GLuydiMe4" id will not open through this way ?  Why is it .. ?

Answer (score 0):

On Android devices, you can use an `Intent` for Youtube videos:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E43mgXNl0xc"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue none of the answers worked for me, **The issue is that video format is not proper** this video worked for me

```
String vidAddress = "http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4";
```