# How to play multiple Youtube videos in VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview, rtsp, youtube-channels

I am getting multiple Youtube URL from Json through this [link](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mashable/uploads?&v=2&alt=jsonc)!
    First Thing is that when i play one url VideoView . I am getting `## Sorry ! this video cannot played##`. I have searched for this where RTSP url support VideoView.

Now How I'll get RTSP Url. & How to Play Multiple Videos?
    My VideoView Code Is:-

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
Button youtube=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("http://m.youtube.com/details?v=LKLHoNy5xpE");
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: > you can try this http://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/ > or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832379/couldnt-open-file-on-client-side-trying-server-side-error-in-android